# Will a PXIe card fit in a PCIe slot?

Tags: pci-express

I cannot figure out for the life of me if a National Instruments PXIe card ([such as this](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/208291)) will fit and work correctly in a standard PCIe slot. Their website is not helpful at all in answering this question. It seems to be hinted at that a chasis ([like this](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/208074)) is required to operate any PXIe cards but I can't tell if it's just something extra they want to sell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That card will not work in a PCIe slot. You will need to purchase a PXI chassis. It probably is them just wanting to sell you something (by using a proprietary connector), but not something you can get out of.

Answer (score 1):

It is [electrically compatible, but physically incompatible](http://www.interfacebus.com/PXIe_Bus_Description.html). You may be able to find an adapter for it, but I have no clue where.

> PXIe ... is electrically identical to the PCIe specification, except it uses the Euro (VME) card 3U/6U format with 2mm connectors.

Comment: Europe always has to do it differently... SCART, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

No, 2 different standards. They are not interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

According to this page [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/2876), you will basically need a chassis because PCIe does not work with PXIe, although, according to this picture and the previously linked page, when you get their chassis, it is backwards-compatible with PCIe. 
[image]